# How to order file paths in lexicographical order? Python

Tags: python, file, sorting, path, lexicographic

I need to sort a list of file paths into lexicographic order such as the output is sorted like this:

```
C:\Test\Project1\Example\test1.txt   
C:\Test\Project1\Example\test2.txt   
C:\Test\Project1\Example\Sub\meee.txt       
C:\Test\Project1\Example\Sub\test1.txt    
C:\Test\Project1\Example\Sub\youu.txt   
C:\Test\Project1\Example\Zzz\zzz.py
```

When I sort it naturally I receive `C:\Test\Project1\Example\Sub\meee.txt` before `C:\Test\Project1\Example\test1.txt` and do not want that.

Comment: The lexicographic order is what you got from Python, what you want is not lexicographic order, so you will have to design a custom sorting function.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the logic by which `test1` should come before `Sub`? `T` is not before `S` in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` with a custom key which gives priority to files in the root directory:

```
L = [r'C:\Test\Project1\Example\test1.txt', r'C:\Test\Project1\Example\test2.txt',
     r'C:\Test\Project1\Example\Sub\meee.txt', r'C:\Test\Project1\Example\Sub\test1.txt',   
     r'C:\Test\Project1\Example\Sub\youu.txt', r'C:\Test\Project1\Example\Zzz\zzz.py']

def sort_key(x):
    splits = x.split('\\')[4:]
    return len(splits), splits

res = sorted(L, key=sort_key)

['C:\\Test\\Project1\\Example\\test1.txt',
 'C:\\Test\\Project1\\Example\\test2.txt',
 'C:\\Test\\Project1\\Example\\Sub\\meee.txt',
 'C:\\Test\\Project1\\Example\\Sub\\test1.txt',
 'C:\\Test\\Project1\\Example\\Sub\\youu.txt',
 'C:\\Test\\Project1\\Example\\Zzz\\zzz.py']
```